# Failed to invoke the service, WCF Test Client?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcftestclient

I have a WCF service. I have a problem with it.
Whenever I call a method with large response data (e.g: `GetUserByUsernameWithAllRelations()`) from service (with WCF Test Client) the following error occurred.

```
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:17497/SmartService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ISmartService.GetUserByUsername(String username)
   at SmartServiceClient.GetUserByUsername(String username)

Inner Exception:
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Inner Exception:
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

Inner Exception:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

But if I call a method with a small response data (e.g: `GetAllUsersCount()`) it works without any problems.

WCF Test Client config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISmartService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                    sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />              
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:17497/SmartService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISmartService" contract="ISmartService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_ISmartService">              
            </endpoint>

        </client>

        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior">
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Behaviors.EndpointBehavior">
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>        

    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My WCF Service config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SmartizEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SmartizDataModel.csdl|res://*/SmartizDataModel.ssdl|res://*/SmartizDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\MSSQLSERVER2012;initial catalog=xxxx;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

**P.S:** 
Here, in our company, we have a proxy in our windows to use LAN and the Internet. I disabled it but nothing changed.

**Edit:**
WCF Test Client Error:

```
Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.
```

Comment: Some debugging ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821687/wcf-an-error-occurred-while-receiving-the-http-response-to-http-xxxxx-servic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After couple of hours searching I could found the solution:
 
http://sanderstechnology.com/2013/more-with-the-entity-framework-v6-rc1/12423

I had to add `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` attribute to each entity.
In above link you can learn how to do it with T4 in EntityFramework

Comment: Well Mohammad, you saved me on this one. Thanks a bunch!