# HTTP response exception in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, gmap.net

I'm making WCF service using GMap.NET library to work with maps, routes.. I`ve written a code, checked it with my WPF app- everything works clear. Then I copied all code to my WCF service, built it, connected to my app, and used all methods i want from my service, and while app was running(using methods from servise), an exception was thrown. The text of that exception:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   'localhost...\Service'. This could be due to the service endpoint
>   binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP
>   request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the
>   service shutting down). See server logs for more details

What's the problem? I`ve found nothing in Internet. If you know, how to solve that proplem, let me know, please

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: Did you check the server logs?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15822764/2813117 it may help